# Add alias symbol to class variable in Java

Tags: java, spring

I am having a requirement to develop a JSON formatted data to pass to our 3rd party API vendor. One of the parameters require the variable to have alias symbol in front, but I am unsure the best way to put it.

**JSON Example**

```
"Test": [
            {
                "name": "1",
                "@type": "2"
            }
        ],
```

**JAVA test class**

```
public class Test
{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

How do I have the "@" symbol in front of the "type" variable?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @Stultuske to be honest I'm just following the format provided by the vendor, not sure why they put it like that. But if we didn't follow the format, the API will reject our request.

Comment: short answer is: you can't, since it's a variable, not an annotation

Comment: @cleopatez What library or toolkit are you using to create your JSON data?

Comment: @ThomasBehr Im using Gson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have that weird requirement (which makes no sense to me) you can always change the name of a field that is serialized to JSON by using the `JsonProperty` annotation (assuming you are using Jackson of course).

To achieve something like that, simply do something in the lines of:

```java
public class Test {

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("@type")
    private String type;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did have a try on your solution, but it still won't return the @ symbol for type. Is it because I formatted it using Gson?

Comment: Your solution did bring me to the right direction for this, but since I'm using Gson as library, the code needed is @SerializedName("@type") instead of @JsonProperty("@type") which is for Jackson.

Comment: Yeap precisely. Your implementation will depend on the serialization library, as mentioned originally but the base idea should be the same.